# python numpy adding an id to an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

is it possible to add an id to a numpy  array  bacause i have multiple arrays :

```
array1 = np.array([1, 2, 3]) #for b = 0.15
array2 = np.array([4, 5, 6]) #for b = 0.20
array3 = np.array([7, 8, 9]) #for b = 0.25
#........................... to   b = 0.90
```

and i have a function  to calculate b so if b = 0.18  i want  to work  with array 1 and 2 (interpolate between them ) and i dont want to work  with s**witch case** because  i have a lot  of arrays  i want something like :

```
array1 = np.get_array_id(ceil(b))
array2 = np.get_array_id(floor(b))
```

and this is  just an exemple  np.get_array_id does not exist

the real life exemple is table :

[image]

the values to chose are determined by **teta** and **b** teta for the array and b for the rows   exemple :

for teta  = 0.18  i chose  the array teta = 15 and the array  teta = 20 because 0.15 <0.18<0.20  , for b =0.125  i chose the rows  0 and b/4 because 0 <0.125<1/4

Comment: If your arrays are float-arrays, you can set the first element as `b`? And use `array[1:]` everywhere else

Comment: @stochastic13 yes

Comment: Why don't you just use a dictionary? `{'id1':np.array(...), ...}`

Comment: @alec_djinn  because I don't have that much knowledge in python I have edited my post can you tell me how you would go about it please

Comment: @NAS then please learn the basics of Python before playing with numpy

Comment: I am learning, but this is a school work and I am kinda limited by time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list of arrays

```
array_list = []
array_list[1] = np.array([1, 2, 3]) #for teta = 0.15
array_list[2] = np.array([4, 5, 6]) #for teta = 0.20
...
```

And then calculate `id = (teta*100/5)-2` to get your array id

```
id = (teta*100/5)-2
excepted_array = array_list[ceil(id)]
excepted_array2 = array_list[floor(id)]
```

You can do the same for getting right column. `col=(4*b)`

```
col = 4*b
excepted_column1 = ceil(col)
excepted_column2 = floor(col)
```

Comment: yes this something that  can work  but   actually  the arrays are not  1-D arrays  but 2-D   and i have to do  2 interpolation   teta and b:  teta for the array and b for the row  i will edit my post to show a real life exemple

Comment: the first part is  good thank you but i dont get the second part , why b*4 ?? and actually  its the row not the column

Comment: the result  would a 1-D array ( a row ) not a value ,  one row  for each  array

Comment: Your interval space is 1/4. and then by multiply 4 in your b value, you can cast your ceil and floor to a natural number.
For example, if your b is 0.3 you want to get 1st and 2nd row.
0.3*4 = 1.2 -> ceil(1.2) = 2 and floor(1.2) = 1.